# Infinispan clustered REPL_ASYNC cache: command indefinitely bounced between two nodes

Tags: spring-boot, caching, cluster-computing, infinispan

Im running a spring boot application using infinispan 10.1.8 in a 2 node cluster. The 2 nodes are communicating via jgroups TCP. I configured several REPL_ASYNC.

The problem:
One of these caches, at some point is causing the two nodes to exchange the same message over and over, causing high CPU and memory usage. The only way to stop this is to stop one of the two nodes.

More details, here is the configuration.

```java
 org.infinispan.configuration.cache.Configuration replAsyncNoExpirationConfiguration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .clustering()
                    .cacheMode(CacheMode.REPL_ASYNC)
                .transaction()
                    .lockingMode(LockingMode.OPTIMISTIC)
                .transactionMode(TransactionMode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
                .statistics().enabled(cacheInfo.isStatsEnabled())
                .locking()
                    .concurrencyLevel(32)
                    .lockAcquisitionTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .isolationLevel(IsolationLevel.READ_COMMITTED)
                .expiration()
                    .lifespan(-1) //entries do not expire
                    .maxIdle(-1) // even when they are idle for some time
                    .wakeUpInterval(-1) // disable the periodic eviction process
                .build();
```

One of these caches (named `formConfig`) is causing me abnormal communication between the two nodes, this is what happens:

1. with jmeter I generate traffic load targeting only node 1
2. for some time node 2 receives cache entries from node 1 via SingleRpcCommand, no anomalies, even `formConfig` cache behaves properly
3. after some time a new cache entry is sent to the `formConfig` cache

At this point the same message seems to keep bouncing between the two nodes:

- node 1 sends entry `mn-node1.company.acme-develop sending command to all: SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='formConfig', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=SimpleKey [form_config,MECHANICAL,DESIGN,et,7850]`
- node 2 receives the entry `mn-node2.company.acme-develop received command from mn-node1.company.acme-develop: SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='formConfig', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=SimpleKey [form_config,MECHANICAL,DESIGN,et,7850]`
- node 2 sends the entry back to node 1 `mn-node2.company.acme-develop sending command to all: SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='formConfig', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=SimpleKey [form_config,MECHANICAL,DESIGN,et,7850]`
- node 1 receives the entry `mn-node1.company.acme-develop received command from mn-node2.company.acme-develop: SingleRpcCommand{cacheName='formConfig', command=PutKeyValueCommand{key=SimpleKey [form_config,MECHANICAL,DESIGN,et,7850],`
- node 1 sends the entry to node 2 and so on and on...

Some other things:

- the system is not under load, jmeter is running only few users in parallel
- Even stopping jmeter this loop doesn't stop
- `formConfig` is the only cache that behaves this way. All the other REPL_ASYNC caches work properly. I deactivated only formConfig cache and the system is working correctly.
- I cannot reproduce the problem with two nodes running on my machine

Here's a more [complete log file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QxM_aTXhn-5nTl-M8N_hxO--6KNuc81T/view?usp=sharing) including logs from both nodes.

Other infos:

- opendjdk 11 hot spot
- spring boot 2.2.7
- infinispan spring boot starter 2.2.4
- using [JbossUserMarshaller](https://infinispan.org/docs/10.1.x/titles/developing/developing.html#jboss_marshalling)

I'm suspecting

- something related to transactional configuration
- or something related to serialization/deserialization of the cached object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only scenario where this can happen is when the `SimpleKey` has different `hashCode()`.

Are there any exceptions in the log? Are you able to check if the `hashCode()` is the same after serialization & deserialization of the key?

Comment: Thank you! Your suggestion lead me here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/24320. I tried to remove the enums from the simpleKey and now it seems to work properly. The only thing is that it has been fixed in spring 5.2.4 and I'm using a newer version. I don't understand if the bug still exists or if the JBossMarshaller is playing a role here.

Comment: A quick google search suggest that `Enum.hashCode()` uses the `System.identityHashCode()`. If that is the case, the enum will have different hashes in node1 and node2 and it shouldn't be used as key for Infinispan. I'll try to do a simple test tomorrow.

Comment: I've made an example here: https://github.com/pruivo/playground/tree/master/enum-test. You should try to avoid using enum or configure a custom `KeyPartitioner` (see https://infinispan.org/docs/stable/titles/configuring/configuring.html#key_ownership)

Comment: Thanks to your example I was able to reproduce the issue here: https://github.com/ecostanzi/playground. The enum was indeed the issue. Just out of curiosity, what I'm still missing is what triggers the infinite message loop. When using enums hashCodes and segments are always different, but replication issue starts (apparently randomly) after some entries have been inserted.

Comment: If the key belongs to segment `X` in node1 and `Y` in node2, the "ping-pong" only happens if node1 is primary-owner of `X` and node2 is primary-owner of `Y`.